# Matter.js: Method to count how many times that an object has rotated?

Tags: javascript, rotation, physics, matter.js

I am creating a project in which a body is picked up and thrown by the user (with a mouse constraint). The body is set so that it can pivot about the constrain point. I need to find out, *from the moment that it is let go*, how many times it fully rotates (+-360 degrees) before landing. Reading the documentation, the only thing that I could find regarding the rotation was *Matter.Body.rotate()* which actually just sets the rotation of a body instead of recording it. How should I go about this?
Basically: How can I count an objects rotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me tbh:

```
var rad = 6.28;
var nrad = -6.28;


Events.on(engine, "tick", function () {
if(boxA.angle > rad){

    rad+=6.28;
    nrad+=6.28;

    hrt +=1;
    //hrt is the rotation c0unter

    }

if (boxA.angle < nrad){

    nrad-=6.28;
    rad-=6.28;

    hrt +=1;

    }

rnum.innerHTML = "Spins: " + hrt;
fnum.innerHTML = fcounter;  });
```